# How do i change the height of the day in the month view of Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I have been looking for a solution to the below problem. When i add events to my fullcalendar the days (in month view) are stretched vertically. The event is causing the day height to be adjusted. Does anybody know how to fix this?

[My calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjUIx.png)

If you notice on march 3rd the events at 1pm and 3:30pm. I would like my calendar events to be closer so the entire calendar is visible like this:

[Fullcalendar image from the fullcalendar website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIrHK.png)

Comment: do you have a large height set on container? Hard to help from image...create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co that replicates issue

Comment: You can set min-height to day content (.fc-day-content) in month view. This will show equal minimum height of all days in month view at some level. Once events are exceed then that particular day with it's week streched.

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert this prop: "dayMaxEventRows: true" and add specific options for each view, [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayMaxEventRows)